# CSS - Can't get overflow:hidden to work when overflowing on right or bottom

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, hidden

I have created a template that contains a panel and a content. Depending on the template's class (Top, Left, Right, or Bottom) the panel will have a different position. The expand and collapse animations are performed using transition and classes.

EDIT:
Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ckkVx/2/
/EDIT

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="../Css/reset.dev.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../Css/V_PanelTemplate.dev.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="../Js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        <script src="../Js/V_PanelTemplate.dev.js" type="text/javascript">
    </head>
    <body class="PanelTemplate Bottom">
        <div class="Panel AutoHide Collapsed">PANEL</div>
        <div class="Content Expanded">CONTENT</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
#CHARSET "UTF-8";

.PanelTemplate {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
.PanelTemplate > .Panel,
.PanelTemplate > .Content {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: ease-in-out 400ms;
       -moz-transition: ease-in-out 400ms;
        -ms-transition: ease-in-out 400ms;
         -o-transition: ease-in-out 400ms;
            transition: ease-in-out 400ms;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Top > .Panel,
.PanelTemplate.Bottom > .Panel {
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Left > .Panel,
.PanelTemplate.Right > .Panel {
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Top > .Content,
.PanelTemplate.Bottom > .Content {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Left > .Content,
.PanelTemplate.Right > .Content {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Top > .Panel {
    top: -90px;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Left > .Panel {
    left: -190px;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Right > .Panel {
    right: -190px;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Bottom > .Panel {
    bottom: -90px;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Top > .Panel.Expanded {
    top: 0;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Left > .Panel.Expanded {
    left: 0;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Right > .Panel.Expanded {
    right: 0;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Bottom > .Panel.Expanded {
    bottom: 0;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Top > .Content {
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Left > .Content {
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Right > .Content {
    right: 200px;
    left: 0;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Bottom > .Content {
    bottom: 100px;
    top: 0;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Top > .Content.Expanded {
    top: 10px;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Left > .Content.Expanded {
    left: 10px;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Right > .Content.Expanded {
    right: 10px;
    }
.PanelTemplate.Bottom > .Content.Expanded {
    bottom: 10px;
    }
/* Test CSS */
.PanelTemplate > .Panel {
    background: #777;
    color: #FFF;
    }
.PanelTemplate > .Content {
    background: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    }
```

And, if needed, the JavaScript code:

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var CLOSE_DELAY = 1000;

        var $panel = $('.PanelTemplate > .Panel.AutoHide').first();
            $content = $('.PanelTemplate > .Content').first();

        $panel.mouseenter(function() {
            $panel
              .addClass('Expanded')
              .removeClass('Collapsed')
              .data('isMouseOver', true);
            $content
              .removeClass('Expanded')
              .addClass('Collapsed');
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            $panel.data('isMouseOver', false);
            // Waiting a short time in case the mouse accidently leaves
            var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                // If it's no longer over after time out, closing
                if( ! $panel.data('isMouseOver')) {
                    $panel
                      .removeClass('Expanded')
                      .addClass('Collapsed');
                    $content
                      .addClass('Expanded')
                      .removeClass('Collapsed');
                }
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }, CLOSE_DELAY);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

When I'm using the classes Top or Left on my template, everything works as intended, but when I use either Right or Bottom, the panel, while moving out of the body, expends the window and causes scroll bars to appear.

I read in another question related to `overflow:hidden` than it could be due to a relatively positioned element, but I don't have any. I also tried to position the html tag and add `overflow:hidden` to it too, but it didn't help either.

What can I do to prevent this ?

Comment: Can you make a simplified fiddle please

Comment: why is there so much css? there is no .PanelTemplate.Left and Right in your html

Comment: **to Huangism** It is as simple as it can be. I added nothing that's not required except background and text colors, and dumb text for the panel and the content. Here is a fiddle if you want : http://jsfiddle.net/ckkVx/1/

**to caramba** There is no Right or Left in the HTML because it is meant to only use one at a time (i.e the panel can't be both on the left and the right for example). Here is an example with Bottom, but i could also have used Left, Right, or Top instead, that's just one of the four possibilities. Bottom and Right are the ones that don't work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix your issue-

```
body {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This is surprising me, when i tried doing this before i post this question, it didn't work, and now it does, i don't get it. :o
Anyway, it works now, thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the CSS. *Vector*'s answer with `max-width: 100%;` is great, but if that doesn't work then use the `!Important` override feature. For Example:

```
.PanelTemplate {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden; !Important
 }
```

That will help override the other rules on overflow!

Comment: In how does this add anything to the existing answer?

Comment: I was suggesting that if the Max-width didn't work then try the !Important rule. It helps give priority to overflow: hidden over the other rules in the .paneltemplate.

Comment: Since the OP accepted _Vector_'s answer it seems like it helped. Else you might write something like "If Vector's answer doesn't help, try ..."

Comment: Sorry about that,I just edited the answer! Thanks for spotting the confusion!